# SVN checkout not working on Xcode

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode4, svn-checkout

Whenever I try doing a checkout of a project from Xcode 4.5, I get an error saying "Request Timed Out" after a little while (the process doesn't stop though, it keeps on trying without getting anything ever).

The project is accessible with other svn clients (like Versions) and the certificate for its address is set on "trusted" in the keychain.

I even tried with someone else's Xcode, reproducing the exact same steps at the same time, the other laptop returning a successful checkout...

Help please ?

Thanks.

Comment: This won't help your problem, but I would suggest not using SVN with Xcode, it's just broken and buggy as hell. Either use git, or an external SVN client.

Comment: What efficient SVN client for mac would you suggest in that case ? My "Versions" expires in a few days.

Comment: If you don't want to command line client, I recommend SmartSVN, there's a free foundation version which supports all basic functions and some more. It's java based, that's the downside. But it works.

Comment: Ok I will try that, thanks. What about merges ? That's what I would like to use in Xcode mostly.